# Jackson: how to parse JSON list to Java set?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json with an array like

```
fieldName:["A","B", "C"]
```

and I am trying to parse it into Set but it ends up with the error:

```
Problem deserializing property 'fieldName' (expected type: [collection type; 
class java.util.Set, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]; 
actual type: java.util.ArrayList), problem: argument type mismatch
```

I would need a set in result since it is much faster to check presence of an element in a set.

Comment: Can you share the code that produces this error? It would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, if you mean `{"fieldName":["A","B", "C"]}`, then the outer most JSON structure is a JSON object, which can't be deserialized into a `Set`. Use `Map` and get the corresponding entry.

Comment: @toKrause no I do not mean this. fieldName deserializes into List OK but not to set.

Comment: @Askar Please show us the code that produces the error.

Comment: @AskarIbragimov please post the complete json the code you are using